# JavaScript Style Background Property not working

Tags: javascript

```js
let img1 = document.getElementById("i1");

console.log(img1.style.background);
```

```css
#i1 {
  background: url("img/IMG_2359.jpg");   
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "img" id = "i1"> </div>
  <div class = "img" id = "i2"> </div>
  <div class = "img" id = "i3"> </div>        
</div>
```

When I console.log my code it outputs a blank entry but I need it to output " **url("img/IMG_2359.jpg")"**
All of my code is in the same file.

Comment: Since your background is inside of a css class you can't get it via the style attribute because you have no style attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
let img1 = document.getElementById("i1");

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(img1).getPropertyValue('background-image'));
```

```css
#i1 {
  background: url("img/IMG_2359.jpg");   
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "img" id = "i1"> </div>
  <div class = "img" id = "i2"> </div>
  <div class = "img" id = "i3"> </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: I was just answering the same. Upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

It may help to change background to **background-image**.

```
    #i1 {
       background-image: url("img/IMG_2359.jpg");   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(img1).backgroundImage);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property)`

```js
let img1 = document.getElementById("i1");

console.log(
  window
    .getComputedStyle(i1)
    .getPropertyValue("background-image")
);
```

```css
#i1 {
  background: url("img/IMG_2359.jpg");   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img" id="i1">1</div>
  <div class="img" id="i2">2</div>
  <div class="img" id="i3">3</div>
</div>
```